# Azure - PGP/GPG decryption of files

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

The client sends files through SFTP (using [SFTP on Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/sftp-creation-template/sftp-on-azure/)) to File Share, then I transfer it to Blob using Data Factory. Files are encrypted using GPG or PGP. I looking for way to decrypt it on the server. I was thinking about additional step in Data Factory which would trigger a python script. Is this task doable in Azure?

Comment: Yes, of course, you can do this on ADF or Azure Databricks. In fact, you should also consider using Azure Batch for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an Azure function that use the blob storage trigger to decrypt the files as soon as they arrive.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-storage-blob-triggered-function

Comment: Do you have a code sample of decrypting a gpg file in blob triggered function? That link didn't have anything about it.