# How to Decrypt PGP File in Azure Blob with Python, Key, and Passphrase

Tags: python

How do you decrypt a PGP file in an Azure Storage Explorer blob with python? The PGP file is a zip file. I have a public and secret key with a passphrase.
I tried this in Visual Code.

```
import pgpy
emsg = pgpy.PGPMessage.from_file("path to the file from the client that was encrypted using your public key")
key,_  = pgpy.PGPKey.from_file("path to your private key")
with key.unlock("your private key passpharase"):
    print (key.decrypt(emsg).message)
```

The error is 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59684353/azure-pgp-gpg-decryption-of-files

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure - PGP/GPG decryption of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59684353/azure-pgp-gpg-decryption-of-files)

Answer (score 0):

I tried again and this decrypted the PGP file. http://jackofalltradesmasterofsome.com/blog/2023/03/17/decrypt-and-save-a-text-or-cvs-with-pgpy-and-python/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This works for a file with keys on my desktop. How do you apply it to a file in Azure Storage Explorer?
http://jackofalltradesmasterofsome.com/blog/2023/03/17/decrypt-and-save-a-text-or-cvs-with-pgpy-and-python/